# Load more posts plugin

Tags: php

I edited this php file to load 12 posts at a time, however I realise the code also maxed the number of pages load to be 12. After the 12th page, it says 'no more posts to load' even though there are still posts. How should I edit this code in order to allow infinite pages to be loaded with 12 posts loaded each time?

```
<?php

function pbd_alp_init() {
global $wp_query;

// Add code to index pages.
//if( !is_singular() ) {    
    if( !is_single() ) {
    // Queue JS and CSS
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'pbd-alp-load-posts',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/load-posts.js',
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0',
        true
    );

    wp_enqueue_style(
        'pbd-alp-style',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/style.css',
        false,
        '1.0',
        'all'
    );



    // What page are we on? And what is the pages limit?
    $max = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

            if(is_page_template('template-blog.php')){
        $max = wp_count_posts()->publish;
        //default is 6 posts per page
        if($max % 12 == 0){
            $max = $max / 12;
        }else{
            $max = (int)($max / 12) + 1;
        }
    }
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') > 1 ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    // Add some parameters for the JS.
    wp_localize_script(
        'pbd-alp-load-posts',
        'pbd_alp',
        array(
            'startPage' => $paged,
            'maxPages' => $max,
            'nextLink' => next_posts($max, false)
        )
    );
}
```

}
 add_action('template_redirect', 'pbd_alp_init');

?>

Answer (score 0):

You don't want infinite pages to load at once.  You want to send a query for 12 - 36, depending on how your site traffic is.  Then every subsequent request will get the next in the order.  Use count() the total posts, and do a for loop. save the last post ID in javascript for the next ajax call to start on, +12, etc..  Is this good, or do you you need me to hand write the code for you?

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks so much for your answer! I'm sorry, because I'm a newbie, not sure what to do, is it ok if you help me write the code?

Comment: Which ever wordpress functions you have problems with, type the name of the function in google, the top answer should be the definition on wordpress's website.  On their site, it is well documented how to use the function along with all it's options, and examples.  As for coding it for you, you should probably hire someone if you don't feel comfortable doing it yourself.  If your site had any reasonable amount of traffic going to it, you need to optimize wordpress anyways. Hacking into core files, as well as theme files. Good luck, keep learning, and keep coding.